# Getting an error while calling a soap service from .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, basic-authentication, soap-client

I'm trying to call a SOAP service shared by our client (Not sure whether the soap service is a WCF or created by Java). I have added the service as a connected service using the Microsoft WCF Web Service Provider. Basic authentication is implemented for the service. When I try to consume that service using the below mentioned code (c#), I'm getting an error.

```
var results = new object();
string username = "abc";
string password = "xyz";
MyServiceReference.MyServiceStronglyTypedTypeClient soapClient = new MyServiceReference.MyServiceStronglyTypedTypeClient();
var httpBinding = soapClient.Endpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;

httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
soapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
soapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
results = await soapClient.getTotalsByMemberIdAsync("001","ADM","");
```

Error message is as follows.

```
Could not send Message.

Stack trace:

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult(
```

I have been working on this for several hours now and any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I've never run into this, but have you tried connecting via something like SOAP UI? If that connects successfully then I would suggesting looking at your endpoing binding.

Comment: Yes. I have tried with SOAP UI and it is connecting without any issues.

Comment: Do you have a WSDL for the service? Once imported it creates a class and is much easier to use. I've never called a SOAP service that didn't have one so if not I'm afraid I won't be able to offer much more.

Comment: Yes. It do have a WSDL. I'm trying to call the service method using the class/method generated by importing the wsdl only. But, when I try to get the data from the service using the above code, getting this error. Is there an issue with my code ?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say I add a WSDL service called 'webServ'

in the service exists a function called 'getTotalsByMemberIdAsync' which requires string username,string password, string variable1, string variable2, string variable3.

I would call it like so:

```
webServ.WebServices ws = new webServ.WebServices();
string user = "foo";
string pass = "bar";
string XMLResults = ws.getTotalsByMemberIdAsync(user,pass,"001","ADM","");
```

Does this resolve your issue?

Comment: No. I have basic authentication also have given the credentials (username and password) also, other than the above mentioned. But, still the When I try to invoke that method, I'm getting this error.

Comment: @AnishV any chance I could see the WSDL?

Comment: Sorry. That's shared by client and cannot be disclosed. They now confirmed that it is developed by Java.